# why this jquery code creates many copies of the "X-button"?

Tags: jquery

I can't find the problem.  Why is this code making many copies of the "X"-button when I close the red-layer and when I click the first button again?

I thought the `init` worked like a proper constructor that just runs one time, right?

Here is a jsfiddle illustrating the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/yoniGeek/mWghr/

Thanks for your time!

Y/

the html:

```
<div class="Main">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
         Phasellus non nisl mauris. Phasellus eget viverra mi. 
         Curabitur elementum tristique nibh, et faucibus eros 
         fermentum ut. Pellentesque non nisi augue. 
         Nulla facilisis ultrices malesuada. Sed bibendum lacus 
         sed lorem auctor rutrum. 
         iam semper justo id diam
     </p>
     <p id="last_child" > Lorem ipsum dolor 
         sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
         Phasellus non nisl mauris. Phasellus eget viverra mi. 
         Curabitut interdum velit ultricies. 
     </p>
     <div id="layer_on" ></div>
 </div>
```

the jquery-code:

```
(function(){

    $('html').addClass('js');

    //var red_layer;
    var red_layer = {
        red_box: $('#layer_on'),

        init: function() {
            $('<button></button>', {
                text: 'push me'
            }).insertAfter('.Main #last_child').on('click', this.show);
        },

        show: function() {
            red_layer.close.call(red_layer.red_box);
            red_layer.red_box.show();
        },

        close: function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('<span class="close">X</span>').prependTo(this).on('click', function() {
                $this.hide();
            });
        }
        //anonymous function

    }; // red_layer object ends

    red_layer.init(); //We call it back (the function )

})();
```

Comment: Putting this on jsFiddle would be VERY helpful

Comment: @Brian it's!! klick on "HERE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add the close button in the `init` method?  You only need to add the button once.  As it is, you are adding the `X` button every time you show the box.  Every time you click `push me`, you call `show()`, which in turn calls `.close()`, which prepends another `X` to the box.  Instead, call close from your `init` function:

```
var red_layer = {
    red_box: $('#layer_on'),

    init: function() {
        // Console.log(this);
        $('<button></button>', {

            text: 'push me'

        }).insertAfter('.Main #last_child')
                .on('click', this.show);

        red_layer.close.call(red_layer.red_box);  // <--- HERE
    },

    show: function() {
        // NOT HERE

        red_layer.red_box.show();
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xwmVr/

I would argue that your `close` method doesn't need to be a method.  It simply adds the `X` button, which seems like a one-time thing.  It also is not obvious what it is doing.  It seems like calling `close` would actually close the box, but it doesn't in this case.

Comment: oh exactly inside the INIT (cuz it's the only constructor right?): thanks man! The syntax of jquery is making me crazy (im not used to it yet...how methos and functions are presented...mm,mm

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mWghr/1/

Basically check whether close button is already there, then don't prepend

```
if($this.find('.close').length == 0) {
```

Comment: ohh thanks....didn't know that u could check it in this way...what do u check here the length of the class? mm,mm

Comment: It is not useful to make a call to add the button every time you click, but then prevent it all but the first time.  This is what `init` methods are for.

Comment: @YoniGeek basically checks whether a span with class `close` is already there, nvm tho, just follow @Jeff's `useful` solution

Answer (score 0):

Since you're appending span tag in the close function multiple times, you see multiple 'x's. I rewrote your close function like so, and it works perfect.

```
    close: function() {
        var that = $(this);
        that.html('<span class="close">X</span>');
        that.on('click', function() {
            that.hide();
        });
    }
```

Comment: This would replace any contents in the box with just a close button.